# Contrary to Python 3.1 Docs, hash(obj) != id(obj). So which is correct?

Tags: python, hash

The following is from the Python v3.1.2 documentation:

From The Python Language Reference Section 3.3.1 Basic Customization:

```
object.__hash__(self)

... User-defined classes have __eq__() and __hash__() methods 
by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except
with themselves) and x.__hash__() returns id(x).
```

From The Glossary:

```
hashable

... Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are 
hashable by default; they all compare unequal, and their hash 
value is their id().
```

This is true up through version 2.6.5:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010 21:48:26) ...
...
>>> class C(object): pass
...
>>> c = C()
>>> id(c)
11335856
>>> hash(c)
11335856
```

But in version 3.1.2:

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 21 2010, 00:41:52) ...
...
>>> class C: pass
...
>>> c = C()
>>> id(c)
11893680
>>> hash(c)
743355
```

So which is it? Should I report a documentation bug or a program bug?
And if it's a documentation bug, and the default `hash()` value for a user
class instance is no longer the same as the `id()` value, then it would be 
interesting to know what it is or how it is calculated, and why it was
changed in version 3.

Comment: Not sure StackOverflow is the right place to be saying this...

Comment: Note that it's not even necessarily true that `x.__hash__() == id(x)` in CPython 2.6:  on a platform (e.g., 64-bit Windows) where `id` values bigger than `LONG_MAX` are possible, the `id(x)` value could be truncated to give the hash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing this was a change made in Python 3.x to improve performance.  Check out [issue 5186](http://bugs.python.org/issue5186), then look a little more closely at your mismatched numbers:

```
>>> bin(11893680)
'0b101101010111101110110000'
>>> bin(743355)
'0b10110101011110111011'
>>> 11893680 >> 4
743355
```

It's probably worth reporting as a documentation bug.

Comment: All questions answered, and more. Thanks.